# Update in Coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have a Device Entity in which Data sample

```
data: {
    company = ddd;
    name = jje;
    version = dd;
})
```

I want to update name where company equal to ddd.
Here is my code .Please help

```
-(IBAction)update:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDelegate = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [requestData setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [requestData setEntity:entityDescriptionDelegate];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objectsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsArray) {

        NSLog(@"%@",object);
        NSLog(@"%@",objectsArray);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)update:(id)sender
 {
  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDelegate = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
  NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [requestData setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
  [requestData setEntity:entityDescriptionDelegate];
  NSError *error;
  NSArray *objectsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];


  for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsArray) {
    [object setValue:@"Updated Name" forKey:@"name"];
    [object setValue:@"Updated version" forKey:@"version"];
  }


  if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help. Change YOUR_VALUE text to real value

```
-(IBAction)update:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescriptionDelegate = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestData setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [requestData setEntity:entityDescriptionDelegate];
    [requestData setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company == YOUR_VALUE"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objectsArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestData error:&error];

    for (Device *object in objectsArray) {
        object.name = @"YOUR_VALUE";
        object.version = @"YOUR_VALUE";

        [managedObjectContext save:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: for (Device *object in objectsArray) {

Comment: what is device in this line.

Comment: You can generate this object with your Entity via Xcode. Select your .xcdatamodeld file, then choose Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...

Answer (score 0):

just change for loop as follow

```
 for (Device *object in objectsArray) {
            object. company = @"newName";
        }
 [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Comment: What is device Device is my entity name

Comment: its entityName  as in question [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *requestData = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]